# Interface Julia with nauty

Tags: graph, julia, isomorphism

I would like to find the automorphism group of a (bipartite) graph (it is an object created using the LightGraphs package), and to do this I would like to call nauty in Julia. Is it possible? If yes, how would you do that?

I read the documentation and it seems that Julia has a C interface... 
http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may get a more useful answer if you link to the package and give example lessons of the functions in C you wish to call.  Yes, you will need to use ccall, whose documentation you have already found.

Comment: Well, what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:
[grape](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/grape/grape4r7/manual/CHAP008.htm)
(I am referring to another implementation of nauty in GAP) A function like AutGroupGraph is what I am looking for.

Comment: I meant a link to the package you would like to wrap, including explicit code for the call in C to that package,  that does not require us to read two different websites whose code has unknown license restrictions.

Comment: Alternatively, if there is a Python wrapper then you may be able to start off by using PyCall.

Comment: Ok, I installed the packege PyCall in Julia and the module pynauty in Python. Now the only problem is that when I try to call pynauty in Julia using:
`@pyimport pynauty`
I receive the following error:
`ERROR: PyError (:PyImport_ImportModule) <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
ImportError('No module named pynauty',)`

Comment: You installed it with a different version of Python than the one PyCall is using. Do Pkg.build("PyCall") to see which one PyCall needs. (This can also be changed.)

Comment: Before building PyCall gave: `PyCall is using /Users/Marco/.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/bin/python (Python 2.7.12)`
Now I set `ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/local/bin/python"` which is to the path I get typing `which python`. If I build PyCall, I get: `PyCall is using /usr/local/bin/python (Python 2.7.12) at /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7, libpython = /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7`. However `@pyimport pynauty`
gives the same error. My pynauty is in `./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`. Do I have to set the path of python libs in julia?

Comment: How did you install pynauty? With pip? The pip that you used must correspond with this same installation of Python. Another solution is to set the Python env variable (as you did above)  to the empty string, and the  rebuild PyCall. This will install Julia's own private Python installation using conda. You then do using Conda; Conda.add("pynauty") to install

Comment: Ah, I see that you were using the Julia installed conda version. So if you go back to that and do the conda instruction above it should work (as long as conda knows about pynauty)

Comment: I think I found a solution. I did not find a way for Julia Conda to talk to pynauty. I defined `ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/local/bin/python"` and built PyCall. After `using PyCall`, I ran `unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")`, as explained in the [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) section of PyCall documentation. Now I can import pynauty in Julia. Testing now, thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course I have problems parsing the PyObjects. I can create a pynauty graph with  `g = pynauty.Graph(4)` but do not know how to add edges. 
According to [pynauty documentation](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~peter/software/pynauty/html/guide.html), this should work `g.connect_vertex(0, [1, 2, 3])`, but it gives `ERROR: type PyObject has no field connect_vertex`

Comment: Try `g[:connect_vertex](0, [1,2,3])`. This is the Julia syntax for calling methods of Python objects.

Comment: Good point. However in this way, I get `ERROR: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
ValueError('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()',)`